# View computer specs on domain with XP computers

Tags: gratis, hardware, windows-xp

Is there a freeware program for viewing computer specs on domains with XP computers, that can list basic specs for all computers in the domain?

I want basic specs, like how much RAM, hard drive space, and which CPU they have.

Comment: There's a method on [windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg144582.aspx), but i'm not too sure of xp... (let me test and get back to it)

Comment: ok, tnx :) @DylanCorriveau

Comment: The method @DylanCorriveau mentions is supported in windows xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Windows Powershell Script that can compile an excel sheet of the Hardware, OS, System, Processor, Memory, Disk, and Network information of the computers in a domain.

[Computer Inventory Script](http://www.powershellpro.com/why-i-no-longer-hate-writing-documentation/614/)

Authors words:

> The Computer Inventory Script enumerates Hardware, OS, System, Processor, Memory, Disk, and Network information and neatly organizes it in an Excel file. I’ve provided Version 2 of the script that allows you to choose a number of computer resources; all computers in the domain, all servers in the domain, computers from a list maintained in a text file, and the ability manually pick a computer. Version 2 of the PowerShell script also allows you to send credential information should you wish to logon the remote computer with an alternative user account. This is helpful for DMZ servers as well as stand alone servers that are not members of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method built into [windows XP and up](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg144582.aspx) that facilitates this.

It's done using a remote desktop connection (if that's a possibility in your domain...).

It also fulfills all of your requirements (RAM, Hard Drive Space, etc)